# loop to put cell combinations with if statements

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet where all data from 3 worksheets will be put under each other starting from cell D1.
In the columns A till C, calculated combinations of cells from columns just pasted will be placed.
for example:

```
cell A2 will be: D2 & E2
Cell B2 will be: D2 & E2 & if (G2 = "" ; F2 ; G2)
cell C2 will be: D2 & E2 & if (H2 = "" ; if (G2 = "" ; F2 ; G2) ; H2)
```

When I have only one column to fill (column A), I have:

```
Sub M_snb()
  for each sh in sheets(Array("uitdraai FD", "uitdraai asw", "uitdraai food"))
    sn=sh.cells(1).currentregion.offset(1).columns(1)
    sp=sh.cells(1).currentregion.offset(1)

    for j=1 to ubound(sn)
      sn(j,1)=sp(j,2)&sp(j,3)&sp(j,4)
    next

    sh.cells(1).currentregion.offset(1).columns(1)=sn
  next
End Sub
```

This works fast and perfectly, but uses CurrentRegion.
I have been trying to change this script so I could use it for the other 2 columns (column B and column C), but so far, I have not succeeded doing so.

When I change the first line of the code, and change cells(1) to cells(4) I see the code starts from cell D1 which is oke. Even currentregion.offset(1) goes right. But when I add .columns(1) I receive an error.
(I tried everything by putting .select at the end, and step by step expanding the code to see what happens).

`error 438:
this property or method are not supported by this object.`

How can I achieve my goal in the most efficient way?

(this is the basis, I have additional `if` statements (sometimes, the value of the cells in column F is 'Zelfzorg ASW' which has to be changed to 'Zelfzorg'

I hope someone can help me and supply me a code to perform my desired operations.

I am trying to learn this as much as possible but I do not understand what happens in the code above

Comment: You get that error because `.columnn` is not s property of `Cell`. I don't know what you want to do, can't follow your explanation. But if you want to select the column, you can use `EntireColumn` property.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. What I'm trying to do is that the code checks if the cells in column D are empty or not. For each row where the cell in column D is not empty (no value!), the code has to put the mentioned combinations in the cells in columns A, B en C. This has to be done until the last row in column D has been reached and the cells in the columns A,B en C of this last row are filled with the right combinations. The code I posted was suggested by someone on another forum, but I guess this only works for column A because of `CurrentRegion`

Comment: i posted an answer based on your comment. i don't use current region, im not a fan of it. also i don't use loop but utilize the `.Formula` property of `Range` object. hope this is close to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this then based on your comment.
This is faster than looping.

**Not Tested:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sample()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long

For Each ws in Thisworkbook.Sheets(Array("uitdraai FD", "uitdraai asw", "uitdraai food"))
    With ws
        lrow = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lrow > 1 Then '~~> checks whether Column D has value other than header
            .Range("A2:A" & lrow).Formula = "=D2&E2"
            .Range("B2:B" & lrow).Formula = "=D2&E2&IF(G2="""",F2,G2)"
            .Range("C2:C" & lrow).Formula = "=D2&E2&IF(H2="""",IF(G2="""",F2,G2),H2)"
            '~~>next line converts formulas to values, if you don't want it, remove it
            .Range("A2:C" & lrow).Value = .Range("A2:C" & lrow).Value 
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Is this what you're trying?
What the code does is put your formula in Column A, B and C up to where you have value in Column D.
Hope this works for you.
I haven't had time to test, if you encounter problems, just comment it.

Comment: thanks! column a is filled perfectly. But after column A is filled, I get an error: error 1004; application-defined or object-defined error. After that, this line is marked yellow:             .Range("B2:B" & lrow).Formula = "=D2&E2&IF(G2="""";F2;G2)"

Comment: try my edited post. I should have used comma `,` even though your default separator is semicolon `;`.

Comment: I owe you soooooo much! many many thanks! I cannot vote because I do not have enough reputation, but otherwise I would have done it!

Comment: one more question: sometimes, in cells in column F there is the value "Zelfzorg ASW". This should be changed to "Zelfzorg". How can I have this dan by VBA?

Comment: Ah that's easy, but make sure it doesn't have leading or trailing spaces. Add this in your code after `If lrow > 1 Then` statement. `.Range("F2:F" & lrow).Replace "Zelfzorg ASW", Zelfzorg, xlWhole`